# Extract an array in an nested array Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, android-graphview

I have the following code:

```
DataPoint dbPoint[] = new DataPoint[] {
                new DataPoint(0, 1),
                new DataPoint(1, 5),
                new DataPoint(2, 3),
                new DataPoint(3, 2),
                new DataPoint(4, 6)
        };
```

And I wish to remove new `DataPoint(x, y)` value inside, so I can do something like:

```
DataPoint dbPoint[] = new DataPoint[] {};
dbPoint[].add(new Data(1,1);
dbPoint[].add(new Data(2,5);
dbPoint[].add(new Data(3,7);
dbPoint[].add(new Data(4,3);
dbPoint[].add(new Data(5,9);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `DataPoint dbPoint[] = new DataPoint[]{};`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `List` and convert to array using `toArray()`.
Remember, arrays cannot be resized, but collections like `List` can.

```
ArrayList<DataPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(new DataPoint(0, 1));
points.add(new DataPoint(1, 5));
points.add(new DataPoint(2, 3));
points.add(new DataPoint(3, 2));
points.add(new DataPoint(4, 6));
DataPoint[] dbPoint = points.toArray(new DataPoint[points.size()]);

LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dbPoint);
```